# Two-column vertical-numbered lists with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm sure this must be a duplicate, but I cannot find any related answers because so many people are referring to flexbox elements as "lists", when they're not actually using `<ul>` or `<ol>` HTML elements, and are making the equivalent of inline-block div elements.

I have an unordered list that I need to display as two columns using Flexbox. Based on today's reading, I have managed two columns, but the index order of the items goes from left-to-right, instead of top-to-bottom:

```css
ol { display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; flex-direction:row; }
ol li { flex:1 1 auto; width:40%; }
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>Item A</li>
 <li>Item B</li>
 <li>Item C</li>
 <li>Item D</li>
 <li>Item E</li>
 <li>Item F</li>
 <li>Item G</li>
 <li>Item H</li>
</ol>
```

I need the output to be:

```
1. Item A          5. Item E
2. Item B          6. Item F
3. Item C          7. Item G ... etc
```

I tried to swap out `flex-direction:row` with `column`, but it just displayed a single list.

Comment: You need to give a fixed height,..

Comment: check this https://jsbin.com/sapaxomuqe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @ArupRakshit That's it!  I actually don't need the listitem width to be set either if I specify a 5em height on the list.  Thank you!  Perhaps you should post a proper answer and get the deserved rep?!?

Comment: The irony that when in two columns, the readability is reduced massively.  To such a degree that I've turned off the numbering, in which case the flex direction no longer matters...(!)

Comment: I feel if applying flexbox seems hard, it is something grid can be helpful.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to define a maximum height. You're current css lines are not defining "WHERE" the wrap should happen.

```css
ol { display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; flex-direction:row; max-height: 30px}
ol li { flex:1 1 auto; width:40%; }
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>Item A</li>
 <li>Item B</li>
 <li>Item C</li>
 <li>Item D</li>
 <li>Item E</li>
 <li>Item F</li>
 <li>Item G</li>
 <li>Item H</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please post the corrected code with your answer.  As @ArupRakshit has stated, this is indeed correct but isn't a full solution for others with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use columns (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp). It can be pretty janky at times, but it works well for lists in my opinion.

```css
ol {
  columns: 2
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>Item A</li>
 <li>Item B</li>
 <li>Item C</li>
 <li>Item D</li>
 <li>Item E</li>
 <li>Item F</li>
 <li>Item G</li>
 <li>Item H</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ol { 
   display:flex; 
   flex-wrap:wrap; 
   flex-direction:column; 
   height: 100px; 
}
```

no style for `ol li`